# Do not serialize (xml) a specific enum value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums

My program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test
{
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        [XmlEnum(null)]
        Nothing,
        [XmlEnum("A")]
        A,
        [XmlEnum("B")]
        B
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute("firstName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("testEnum")]
        public TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass testClass1 = new TestClass() { Name = "TestClass1", TestEnum = TestEnum.A };
            XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
            StringWriter stringWriter1 = new StringWriter();
            serializer1.Serialize(stringWriter1, testClass1);
            Console.WriteLine(stringWriter1.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine();

            TestClass testClass2 = new TestClass() { Name = "TestClass2", TestEnum = TestEnum.Nothing };
            XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
            StringWriter stringWriter2 = new StringWriter();
            serializer2.Serialize(stringWriter2, testClass2);
            Console.WriteLine(stringWriter2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
firstName="TestClass1" testEnum="A" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
firstName="TestClass2" testEnum="Nothing" />
```

But in case of the Enum Value "Nothing" I would like the following output (Remove the attribute and value all the way):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
firstName="TestClass2" />
```

How do I do this? [XmlIgnore] on a specific Enum Value does not work.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018986/excluding-enum-properties-with-default-values-in-json-response

Comment: @OgnjenBabic That's deserialization, not serialization

Comment: @Heki: We know how to do this in JSON, my question is XML

Comment: @frankhommers It is about serialization also...

Comment: @OgjenBabic: Yes you where right. I am using the "propertyNameSpecified" method now.

Comment: @frankhommers I am aware of that, but I was referencing it because of the nullable part. Anyway, I hope you have found a solution to your problem.