# First Enum Value Not Mapping Correctly In JSON Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, servicestack

I have the following endpoint:

```
        public List<SubBranch> Get(GetSubBranch request)
        {
            SubBranch subBranch = new SubBranch();
            subBranch.BranchId = 1;
            subBranch.Addresses = new List<SubBranchAddress>();
            subBranch.Addresses.Add(new SubBranchAddress { AddressType = AddressType.Postal, City = "A" });
            subBranch.Addresses.Add(new SubBranchAddress { AddressType = AddressType.Test, City = "B" });
            subBranch.Addresses.Add(new SubBranchAddress { AddressType = AddressType.Street, City = "C" });
            return new List<SubBranch> { subBranch };
        }
```

Here is the model:

```
    public class SubBranch
    {
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public List<SubBranchAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubBranchAddress
    {        
        public string City { get; set; }
        public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum AddressType
    {
        Test,
        Street,
        Postal        
    }
```

This is providing the following JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "BranchId": 1,
    "Addresses": [
      {
        "City": "A",
        "AddressType": "Postal"
      },
      {
        "City": "B"
      },
      {
        "City": "C",
        "AddressType": "Street"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see the first value in the `AddressType` enum is not coming through. 
I'd expect `"City": "B"` to have `"AddressType": "Test"` below it.
I have played around with different numbers of enum values in different orders and each time the first value is never coming through.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018986/excluding-enum-properties-with-default-values-in-json-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because I had `JsConfig.ExcludeDefaultValues = true;` in AppHosts.cs.

I could fix it by setting it to `false` or using a non default value for `Test`:

```
public enum AddressType
{
    Test = 1,
    Street,
    Postal        
}
```